# OAuth2 limit of accessTokens per refreshToken

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-ads-api

I have a webapp which has the same codebase, but multiple instances running (round about 20 tomcats).
Inside these apps i need access to the google adwords api and i have to authenticate with OAuth2.

Therefore i save the refreshToken for my api account in a property file (ads.properties) and use it to get an AccessToken.

Since every instance will do so, I will request about 20 accessTokens for one refreshToken.

I'm no wondering if there will be any limit of accessTokens, or can i generate as many of them as i want

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit to the access tokens , I am not sure what is exactly and it could have changed. I think it is 25 , after that the oldest one become inactive - also they last about 60 minutes each before they need to be refreshed.